# Google amp pages not loading properly

Tags: amp-html

https://www-aptadvantage-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.aptadvantage.com/ 
The above link is how Google has cached my amp page and is loading it but there is a huge difference between the above-cached link and below non-cached link.
https://www.aptadvantage.com/
This has created a huge issue in user experience. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: I checked in here https://validator.ampproject.org/#, your website is not valid amp

Comment: Yes, brother, I had to pull down my amp validated website because I was not getting any solution to fix my mobile version amp website. 
fleapo.co/apt is the amp validated website whose files I entered in aptadvantage.com earlier.